# PHP problem How to create a new array to store the value that is not the datetype from a object data[key] field

Tags: php, arrays, new-operator

I have getting the data from the excel by using phpspreadsheet .I try to use the foreach loop to check whether the data with datetype is valid or not and the key question is I want to get the invalid data into a new array else it will return the valid date data and import to the database. Here is my writen code:

```php
foreach ($data_arr as $row) {
     $ActivityStartDate = $row["A"];
     $ActivityEndDate = $row["B"];     
     $date = $excelService-> excel_to_php_timestamp($ActivityStartDate);
     $ActivityStartDate = date("d/m,Y", $date);
```

I want to create a new array to store the data with ActivityStartDate field that is not invalid and show to display hope somebody can help me to figure out how to do this process?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want (your question is a but unclear) you can do something like this:

```php
public function getAll($data_arr): array {
    $result = [];
    $errors = [];
    foreach($data_arr as $line => $row){
        try{
            $result[$line] = $this->getOneRow($row);
        } catch (Exception $exception){
            $errors[$line] = $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
private function getOneRow(array $row): array {
    return [
        'startDate' => $this->getDate($row['A']);
        'endDate' => $this->getDate($row['B']);
        'email' => $this->getEmail($row['C']);
    ];
}
private function getDate(string $value): DatetimeInterface {
    $result = $excelService-> excel_to_php_timestamp($value);
    if($result === false){
        throw new Exception("Invalid date");
    }

    return $result;
}
private function getEmail(string $value): string {
    $result = $excelService->excel_to_email($value);
    if($result === false){
        throw new Exception("Invalid e-mail");
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The significant parts:

- Wrap the creating in a try/catch. This means that if something now goes wrong, your code can catch it and give that back to the activator.
- I made a function the create one row. This makes it more clear what its job is (Google: Single Responsibility). As you can see, I extended that to the two examples
- The examples both have just one task. Do that, or notify why it couldn't. Its their job to do just that one thing and notify "management" (our try/catch) to do something with the conclusion.
- I've added `$line` as key to the result. This way you can notify the user which line requires attention

Comment: My answer is of a higher level than your code, I hope I've explained it enough for you to understand. These are good habbits to learn :)

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO internship (ActivityStartDate,ActivityEndDate,Remark,
      ItemName,ActivityTitle,ActivityClass,DestinationSearch,
      Content,destination,DestinationDisplay,Organizer,Telephone,Email,WebTitle,RelevantWeb) VALUES
         (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; what if I want to insert the data in the database should I use put it back in the try function as your code .

Comment: @JC0203 Inserting is one "job", so it gets its own function. It requires a query and data. You can do `function x(){ $result = $this->getAll($data); if(count($result['errors'])===0){ $this->storeInDB($result);}`